# Service provider implementation using OPEN SAML - JAVA

Tags: java, security, saml-2.0, opensaml

After many analysis, Figured out that SAMLV2.0 is providing excellent service in exchanging  data between the security web domains.

My scenario is I am trying to implement Service Provider(SP) using Shibboleth's new OPEN SAML-JAVA http://shibboleth.net/products/opensaml-java.html .

I have read about ton of documents about the SAML http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language and its components.Still found no document useful in Service provider implementation steps.

Can anyone help me in where to start and what are the steps needed to implement my SP in generally?

Also if there is any sample documentation for open-saml - java is appreciated .

In the implementation, When to generate MetaData(the one which has to agreed upon between the SP and IdP)?

And also Should I only use TestShib https://www.testshib.org/index.html as the testing IdP , Since I am using Shibboleth's OPEN SAML -JAVA library? Is there any other test platform available , Can u suggest me ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation/Explanation sites

1.OPEN SAML JAVA Library

> https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManual

2.MetaData:

> https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/Metadata

Comment: Been there, looked it thru and no good non-soap examples...